# including gwtjsonrpc jar on GWT maven project

Tags: json, maven, gwt, serialization, rpc

I'm trying to optimize the serialization of a GWT Web app.
The app it's maven based and it has 3 modules (project/project-gwt/project-gwt-shared) and one of the methods has to return to client side a large amount of information. This method sends me back a list of large amount of the same DTO, and it consumes a considerable memory and time in the serialization and deserialization.
We made a custom_DTOserializator but although the times is faster, we thinks that it can be improved.

Searching for solutions I found the **[gwtjsonrpc](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/source/browse/README?repo=gwtjsonrpc)** that it's a implementation of the JSON-RPC 1.1 working for GWT. It's integrated on [gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) so I decided try with it.
I downloaded gwtjsonrpc-1.3.jar and i tried to install it with:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=gwtjsonrpc-1.3.jar 
    -DgroupId=com.google.gwtjsonrpc -Dpackaging=jar -DartifactId=gwtjsonrpc 
    -Dversion=1.3 -Dclassifier=sources
```

And I put it in all my poms

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwtjsonrpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwtjsonrpc</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwtjsonrpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwtjsonrpc</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Following the Readme Instruction I create a new Service, serviceImpl, and ServiceAsyn (AppJsonService)and I'm trying to use it on the old module of my app, putting

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwtjsonrpc.GWTJSONRPC'/> 
<servlet path='/AppJsonService' class='com.company.project.server.AppJsonServiceImpl'/>
```

Compiling it with this line (the extra lines id for  permgem memory problems)

```
mvn clean  install:install-file -e -Dfile=gwtjsonrpc-1.3.jar 
-DgroupId=com.google.gwtjsonrpc -Dpackaging=jar -DartifactId=gwtjsonrpc 
-Dversion=1.3  -Dclassifier=sources install -Dmaven.test.skip=true 
-Dgwt.extraJvmArgs="-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xmx1024M"
```

The command install the jar *[INFO] Installing C:\Users\me\Desktop\project\version\pom\gwtjsonrpc-1.3.jar to C:\Users\me.m2\repository\com\google\gwtjsonrpc\gwtjsonrpc\1.3\gwtjsonrpc-1.3-sources.jar*

but in the compilation of the gwt modules it gives me an error that I don't know how to solve

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] GWT Module com.google.gwtjsonrpc.GWTJSONRPC not found in project sources or resources.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: GWT Module com.google.gwtjsonrpc.GWTJSONRPC not found in project sources or resources.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
   ...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: GWT Module com.google.gwtjsonrpc.GWTJSONRPC not found in project sources or resources.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compilationRequired(CompileMojo.java:447)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:308)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:237)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:142)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.utils.GwtModuleReaderException: GWT Module com.google.gwtjsonrpc.GWTJSONRPC not found in project sources or resources
.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.AbstractGwtModuleMojo.readModule(AbstractGwtModuleMojo.java:205)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getLocalInherits(GwtModule.java:189)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getInherits(GwtModule.java:149)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getEntryPoints(GwtModule.java:114)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compilationRequired(CompileMojo.java:361)
        ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're installing a single JAR, instead of 2: one without classifier (`gwtjsonrpc-1.3.jar`) and one with classifier `sources` (actually in Maven it's rather type `java-source`, instead of type `jar`). You'd use the command:

```
mvn install:install-file \
   -DgroupId=gwtjsonrpc -Dpackaging=jar -DartifactId=gwtjsonrpc -Dversion=1.3 \
    -Dfile=gwtjsonrpc-1.3.jar -Dsources=gwtjsonrpc-1.3-sources.jar
```

Oh, and no need to `install-file` **while** building your module!

Note that you can find gwtjsonrpc in a Maven repo at http://gerrit-maven.storage.googleapis.com under GAV `gwtjsonrpc:gwtjsonrpc:1.3`, so just add the `<repository>` to your POM or proxy it in your repository manager and don't bother installing the JARs manually. And at least you'd have the correct POM with the appropriate dependencies!

Comment: Like you suggest, I add the gerrit repository and the dependencies to the poms. But it seems that it's not importing the source because it give me this error : **[ERROR] Line 12: No source code is available for type com.google.gwtjsonrpc.common.AsyncCallback<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?**
Any idea?

Comment: Did you add both `gwtjsonrpc:gwtjsonrpc:1.3` and `gwtjsonrpc:gwtjsonrpc:java-source:1.3`?

Comment: I added to the poms: _<dependency>   <groupId>gwtjsonrpc</groupId> <artifactId>gwtjsonrpc</artifactId>    <version>1.3</version></dependency>_ and _<dependency><groupId>gwtjsonrpc</groupId><artifactId>gwtjsonrpc</artifactId>      <version>1.3</version>   <classifier>sources</classifier>_ It's this wrong? something missing?

Comment: Did you remove the `gwtjsonrpc:gwtjsonrpc` that you previously installed in your local repo?

Comment: I'd removed all. Clean all the dirs and jars. same error. **[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/me/Desktop/application/2.5.0.0/application-gwt/src/main/java/com/company/application/client/Principal.java'[ERROR] Line 2358: No source code is available for type com.google.gwtjsonrpc.common.AsyncCallback<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?** :(

Comment: Strange. Well, then run with `-X` and check a) the classpath used for the GWT compiler, and b) the content of the gwtjsonrpc JARs in your repo. Oh, but maybe start by checking that the `<inherits>` is correct and indeed does include the `AsyncCallback`.

Comment: it's downloading both. In the GWT SDK execution classpath : is _"C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\gwtjsonrpc\gwtjsonrpc\1.3\gwtjsonrpc-1.3-sources.jar_ and _gwtjsonrpc-1.3.jar_ and the .jar s content I think its ok. Anyway my original question it's answered, and maybe I have to open another. Thank you.

Comment: That problem is solved: The `<inherits name='com.google.gwtjsonrpc.GWTJSONRPC' />` **must** be included in **ALL** the modules that have  entry points, altought the module don't use it. And I have 3 diferents modules and now find the class. Thanks!